# Trying to connect two extra monitors of the same type to my laptop. Does not distuinish them

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have connected two identical monitors through a HDMI splitter which the source comes from my laptop. All monitor's display fine, But I cannot extend the display across them as windows thinks that they are the same monitor. I suspect this is due to the fact that it is the same make.

What do I do to extend my display across my laptop monitor and two identical monitors. (Same make, version ect)? In other words, How can I distinguish bettween my two monitors in the windows display settings manager so I can extend my display over all my three monitors?

I am running windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two identical monitors won't cause a problem like this.

If you used a simple "HDMI splitter" then you are splitting the computers output signal between the two monitors at the electrical level, and the computer will only see it as a single device (most likely whichever one responds back first).

You need a port on your video adapter (or a separate video adapter) for each monitor you want to attach, if you want them to be recognized as separate devices by the computer/OS.

Comment: Would a USB -> VGA converter work as a seperate video adapter?

Comment: Three's no such thing as a "USB->VGA converter".  You can get USB video adapters tho; just Google "DisplayLink".

Comment: Oh yes, there are plenty of USB(3.0) to whatever video adapters/converters, with decent performance. I recall a support up to 4 monitors. Even there used to be USB2 devices, but they were a bit sluggish. As a matter of fact, all modern laptop docking stations use a single USB 3.0 link, and then use a IC that converts USB into video.

Answer (score 0):

The monitors are not the issue, the splitter is.
A splitter can only mirror, not extend.

There's a decent explanation here - [Tech-FAQ HDMI Splitter](http://www.tech-faq.com/hdmi-splitter.html)

Answer (score 0):

One HDMI port == one logical monitor for OS. You can't get two different monitors on one HDMI port. However, you can purchase a device that combines two identical monitors into one, like this one [DualHead2o monitor](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/)
[image]
Unfortunately, it has DisplayPort input, so you will need to buy a HDMI-to-DP adapter, if your laptop does not have a native DP.

Alternatively, you can get a number of [USB3-to-video adapters](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71dmCn14kIL._SL1500_.jpg), with VGA/HDMI/DVI outputs, connect them to a USB3 hub, and have many individual displays.